# Как работают асинхронные операции?

Tags: php, асинхронность

Если выполняется асинхронный запрос к БД, это значит что контроль над выполнением передается БД и после вызова она должна вызвать callback?

И если выполняется асинхронный запрос к БД, значит нужно что бы БД или её драйвер, поддерживали асинхронные запросы?

Могу ли я преобразовать синхронную задачу в асинхронную? Если да, то какие способы это сделать существуют?

Задам вопрос о php, что бы поставить эту популярную метку в вопрос.

Я слышал о библиотеках, позволяющих работать в php асинхронно (на основе цикла событий), таких как workerman, reactphp и swoole.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что для корректной асинхронной работы с такими библиотеками, нужны специальные адаптеры для баз данных, для взаимодействия с файлами, сетью и прочим? Ведь PDO, например, блокирует поток выполнения. Стандартное чтение файлов, скорее всего, тоже.

Неужели все возможности предоставляемые такими библиотеками, при желании работать с стандартными классами вроде PDO, сводятся к демонизации скрипта, для [предотвращения его реинициализации](https://habr.com/post/220393/) при каждом вызове?

Comment: драйвер обращается к БД через сокет (сетевой или ОС), а сокеты на уровеня ядра ОС поддерживают асинхронность. Если сокет в неблокирующем режиме, то после отправки данных в него дожидаться ответа не надо. задача может работать дальше. что она собственно и делает, периодически вызывая select (это не SQL select, это такая функция posix ОС) (или другой соответствующий механизм ОС) по которому она узнает, что в сокете появились данные, которые можно читать. когда они появились программа их считывает и вызывает каллбек.

Comment: И всю асинхронность можно реализовать с использованием буквально нескольких вызовов ОС, которые доступны и в php. так что библиотеки ими могут пользоваться. От драйвера БД все что требуется дать прямой доступ к дескриптору сокета (что они обычно позволяют), что бы его можно было слушать в select()